# How can I wait for the `finally` block to run before I expect something in my test?

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs, es6-promise, react-testing-library

I have a file I want to test that looks like this:

```
function handleButtonClick() {
  getData().then(() => {
    // Do something here
  }).catch((err) => {
    // Handler error here
  }).finally(() => {
    // Set color state to yellow
  });
}
```

and my test looks like this

```
let getDataResolve;
const getData = jest.fn();
getData.mockReturnValue(
  new Promise(res => {
    getDataResolve = res;
  })
);

it('should change color to yellow on button click', async () => {
  const myButton = ...do something to grab the button here;
  fireEvent.click(myButton);
  await getDataResolve({});
  expect(// here expect color is set to yellow);
});
```

But my test is failing because by calling `await getDataResolve({})` in my test, I could only trigger the `then` block to run, and the `expect line` is run before the `finally block`. But I want to run that `expect` after the `finally` block is run. Is there anyway I could achieve that? I don't really understand how and when that `finally` block is triggered. Thanks so much for help!

Comment: Hi Bravo, thanks for your comment, so what is your suggestion in my case if I want to do that `expect` line in my test? Changing the code to make the test work apparently is not a good practice.

Comment: There will be a button somewhere in the component and has a onClick handler which is handleButtonClick. In the test, I was able to grab that button and simulate a click on it. I don't know if that clears your confusion.

Comment: Tell you what, since I seem to be confused I'll just remove my comments, and perhaps someone who understands better can help

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

Comment: Try to wrap the `expect` within a `waitFor`  : `await waitFor(() => expect(...));`

Answer (score 0):

tried using `waitFor`, the finally block is getting executed, and value which is been set in `finally` block is available and can be tested using `waitFor` function of react testing library

```
//App.js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('init');

  const getData = () => {
    return Promise.resolve('')
  }

  function handleButtonClick() {
    getData().then(() => {
      setValue('then');
    }).catch((err) => {
      setValue('error');
    }).finally(() => {
      setValue('finally');
    });
  }
  
  return (
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick} data-testid="btn">{value}</button>
  );
}

//app.test.js
describe("<App />", () => {
  it('check if finally block is called', async() => {
    const { queryByTestId } = render(<App />);
    const btn = queryByTestId('btn');
    fireEvent.click(btn);
    await waitFor(() => expect(queryByTestId('btn')).toHaveTextContent('finally'))
  });
});
```